# AOSP build missing libcryptfs

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to build AOSP for the oneplus one and I keep getting this error when tyring to make:

```
'out/target/product/bacon/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libcryptfs_hw_intermediates/export_includes', needed by 'out/target/product/bacon/obj/EXECUTABLES/vold_intermediates/import_includes', missing and no known rule to make it.
```

I already added device/qcom/common and it has a cryptfs folder in it but it's not building it for some reason...

Any ideas?

Comment: If you run a "make -j1" command do you still have the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Android.mk file of system/vold, add this:

device/qcom/common/cryptfs_hw

to the common_c_includes.

Answer (score -1):

It not able to find the cryptfs path, so just add the path in your BoardConfig.mk

TARGET_CRYPTFS_HW_PATH := device/qcom/common/cryptfs_hw